# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when connecting with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, typeerror

So, I was following a tutorial on a messenger clone and they used Firebase. When I used that syntax it showed me error and later i found out they changed the whole syntax. So I tried to do the thing this way and its giving me this typerror.

```
import db from "./firebase";
import { doc,onSnapshot,collection,query } from 'firebase/firestore';
.....
.....
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
          {username: "Shuvo", message: "What's up"},
          {username:"Arnob",message:"Hi"}]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const q = query(collection(db,"messages"));
    const hello = onSnapshot(q,(querySnapshot)=>{
      setMessages(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
    })
  },[])
.....
```

Comment: What line in your code gives that error?

Comment: const q = query(collection(db,"messages"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('messages')
    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot)=>{
      const items = []
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> items.push(doc.data()))
    setMessages(items)
    })
```

Comment: Pardon, is this self-resolved, or was this meant to be an edit to the original question? If it's the former, I would recommend accepting your own answer so that others may see that this question has been resolved

Comment: I cant accept it within 3 days. So have to wait for it.

Comment: Fair, that's a good point. I forgot about [that rule](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Thanks for replying